# Multiple aliases for same type in c#

Tags: c#, delegates, alias, using

I prefer Delegates as arguments wherever possible. 
So I usually come across situation where multiple arguments of a delegate are of same type.I am trying to make more readable. To achieve this, tried with c# keyword "using" directive.

```
using System;
using FirstNumber = System.Int32;
using SecondNumber = System.Int32;
using Result = System.Int32;

public class FunctionPointers
{
    Func<FirstNumber, SecondNumber, Result> add;

    public FunctionPointers(Func<FirstNumber, SecondNumber, Result> op)
    {
        add = op;
    }
}
```

[image: Intellisense snapshot]
From the screen shot, it is clear that alias name is same for all arguments. Is there a way to correct this? or usage of aliases is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I fully understand the rational behind your approach here, but it's important to consider that what you've essentially declared is that:

```
FirstNumber = SecondNumber = Result = System.Int32;
```

Being that all these identities now refer to the same type, `System.Int32`. For that reason, visual studio is choosing to use the first author assigned allias to populate the intellisense.

When it comes to the declaration of delegates, consider that you simply defining the required signature, being the "IN and OUT" type(s). It is the method that is ultimately "wrapped"/"encapsulated" that will provide the identities of the parameters.

To achieve your readability, if indeed you want to go this way, consider defining your own delegate type with the "readable" identities you wanted:

```
public class FunctionPointers
{
    Operator Add;

     public FunctionPointers(Operator addOp)
     {
            Add = addOp;
     }       
}

public delegate Int32 Operator(Int32 FirstNumber, Int32 SecondNumber);
```

Otherwise, the "normal" way, with the identities on the method:

```
Func<Int32,Int32,Int32> add;

public FunctionPointers()
{
    add = AddMethod;
}

public Int32 AddMethod(Int32 FirstNumber, Int32 SecondNumber)
{
    return FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
}
```

Comment: Since the "add" delegate will be assigned by the caller, one way is to define custom delegate as you suggested that would increase readability. It is useful in cases where i limited number of delegates which is not the case in a production code. So I prefer usage of built in delegates instead of designing new custom delegates for each. Also as you said, intellisense is showing the same alias name, is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Understood. Personally, yes, I would say it was expected since now all of those identities refer to the same type. If I may ask; why are you looking to individually "Identify" the types within the function? Since is the caller assigning the method that will determine the usage of parameters. For example you do not yet know if it will be "First + Second" or "Second / First" or any imaginable method of that signature...

Comment: Suppose in a div operation, numerator and denominator are interchanged and passed to function which has same signature as one i defined for add, then it would be completely wrong, If all types are of same type and caller would use sense to identify what is what. It is not possible in all cases if it is in a library function. Isn't it?

Comment: The very purpose of delegate is that they can invoke ANY method of a defined signature, regardless of their function. If you're trying to "protect" against an undesirable method assignment with naming alone you're likely to run into issues further down the line. I'd suggest if you have a defined notation of what can and cannot be assigned to your delegates, define the methods internally, and expose some selection enum to the caller so as they can configure as required?

Comment: well that's a different concern, it can be solved in many ways. I believe we just went off original problem. Your concern and suggestion is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Very true, slight tangent there. To answer your question directly: Fundamentally you've assigned multiple alises to the same type which subsequently are aliases of one another. To my knowledge there is no way to have Visual Studio differentiate between intensities you have defined to be synonymous. Best of luck finding a solution to move forward :)